# SpriteKit changing .atlas contents doesn't remove from memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, atlas

The problem i'm having is when changing contents of .atlas files in XCode. if I change file names or add another image into the atlas folder the changes are not taken by application.

As far as i understand Xcode builds .atlas folder contents as one image and propably created .plist files with coordinates where is which image in the atlas. Is that correct presumption?

If yes where can i find those files to delete them? It's kind of tedious to change the whole atlas name and images every time i need to change the atlas itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a clean (Product/Clean) holding down Shift to get a complete resource rebuild next time. If that's not enough, delete project's derived data and restart Xcode. Xcode is known for caching and reusing everything, so simply deleting the app from device or simulator may not be enough.

Comment: Where can i find project's derived data?

Comment: Window/Organizer/Projects, choose your project, click Delete near to Derived data path.